Got this error (SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module) when I deployed my nextjs app (typescript) to hosting
Yesterday, I've deployed my nextjs app (dev with typescript) to hosting which controlled with DirectAdmin. Then I've created node.js application on the host for my app. I've uploaded my app to the server, run npm install to get node_modules and run.
Then I got this error on my website screen
enter image description here
And I've checked on the error log and I got this logging from server
Log
App 3048195 output: /home/hanhomed/hanho_medicare_webapp/server.ts:1
App 3048195 output: import http, { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';
App 3048195 output: ^^^^^^
App 3048195 output: 
App 3048195 output: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
App 3048195 output:     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
App 3048195 output:     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
App 3048195 output:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
App 3048195 output:     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
App 3048195 output:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
App 3048195 output:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
App 3048195 output:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
App 3048195 output:     at Module.require (/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 3048195 output:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
App 3048195 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
App 3048195 output: 

Looks like the problem came from my server.ts file in project
server.ts
import http, { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';
import url from 'url';
import next from 'next';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  http.createServer(async (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
    try {
      const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url!, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query);
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query);
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end('internal server error');
    }
  }).once('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
  });
});

I've searched the solutions for many hours and I got nothing. But I think these problems came from these file in my project (package.json, tsconfig.json, server.ts)
package.json
{
  "name": "yada_medical_webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx tsx server.ts",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production npx tsx server.ts",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tsx": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "out/types/**/*.ts"
, "server.mts"  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

Thank you for your supporting
To solve this problem
